# SQL Server timeout when requesting roles in MVC5.net application

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am developping a web application in C# with the MVC5.NET framework and the Razor View Engine. For authentication, I am using ASP.NET Identity (as is standard with MVC5) and SQL Server Express 2012 for data storage while I develop. The SQL Server instance runs on the same computer as the application for now. I am developping in Visual Studio 2012 and installed Identity with Nuget.

I am working on implementing role authentification in my application but for some mysterious reason, when the application reaches an authentification attribute (may it be the `Authorize` attribute or a custom `IAuthenticationFilter`), the SQL Server times out. Everything works as intended, I can login, I can request, add and update data, I can register a new account but whenever I try to access the Roles, SQL Server throws a `HttpException` saying: `Unable to connect to SQL Server database.`

Here is the code to my custom `IAuthenticationFilter`:

```
public class RoleAuthenticationFilter : ActionFilterAttribute,IAuthenticationFilter
{
    public String AllowedRole { get; set; }

    public void OnAuthentication(AuthenticationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (!filterContext.Principal.IsInRole(AllowedRole))
            {
                filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
                //throw new HttpException(403, "Unauthorized access");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Result = MVC.Account.Login();
            //throw new HttpException(403, "Unauthorized access");
        }
    }

    public void OnAuthenticationChallenge(AuthenticationChallengeContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = MVC.Account.Login();
    }
}
```

I use it like so: `[RoleAuthentificationFilter(AllowedRole = "User")]`

In the `RoleAuthenticationFilter`, while debugging, I noticed that the exception was thrown on the `IsInRole` call, not before. I inspected the `AuthenticationContext filterContext` instance and noticed that it contains all the information it would need (such as the roles the current user is in.)

My browser displays the following exception:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified).

Comment: I suggeyt you ro some reading training. "SQL Server timeout" is not the same as the error: "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible." which clearly indicates you have either no server or an accessibility problem on network level. This is not a timeout, and it clearly says so.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by:

- updating the Asp.Net identity core to 2.0.1
- adding the providers in the web.config file of the solution.

For some reason, in fact, the creation of Users (and their tables, including those of the Roles) does not need any indication except a "DefaultConnection" being present.

Notwithstanding, when you want to authorize roles, you need to provide the application with the name of the connection string that the RoleProvider will use.

So you may want to add the following to the web.config file (section ).

```
<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider" connectionstringname="DefaultConnection" applicationname="/">
    </add>
  </providers>
</profile>
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider" connectionstringname="DefaultConnection" enablepasswordretrieval="false"
           enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         applicationName="/" />

  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider" connectionstringname="DefaultConnection" applicationname="/" /> 

  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

I got this idea by an article by the usual Scott Hanselman, who however must have been using an older version of the ASP.net forms authentication engine, as the web.config part is all spelled wrong:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx

I hope I have been of help!